# Dropdown menu only appearing when logged in

Tags: plugins, css, cache, debug, browser-compatibility

I'm having a problem where the Hamburger dropdown menu only appears when I'm logged in, I tried on multiple devices and I tried clearning the cache and removing all plugins (except elementor, without elementor no CSS would render to begin with)

Here is a screenshot of the navbar when I'm logged-in

[image]

Here are 2 screenshots of the navbar when I'm not logged in

[image]

[image]

I also tried turning it off or changing the settings but whatever I do this happens, the console contains no errors so I can't pinpoint the reason behind this.
If you want to try for yourself, here is the link where this is currently hosted: https://hosemarket.net

Comment: it might not be possible to solve this by asking online given that we'd need to be logged in to compare the two states and you can't give random people that level of access to your site, especially when there is no code in your question to debug. From what I could tell the menu _is_ there, so it isn't hidden, it's the 3 bars hamburger icon that's missing. A search indicates `eicon-menu-bar` is from Elementor icons, so you're best asking in an Elementor community

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for the reply, yea I understand this could be difficult to debug like that, which Elementor community do you suggest I ask in? As in a stack exchange or a discord server?

Comment: Elementor have their own support channel and I believe users forum.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.